# Getting Over to Someone Why Views Can't Be Used as a Tables

Tags: postgresql

For some reason I'm having a hard time getting over to some people that using a view in Postgres as you would use a table, is a bad idea.

As some background, there are a number of tables containing completely static data that is updated every few months via a batch import into different tables by date - table_201603 or table_201607. A view has then been created called 'table' which clients then use which is just a 'SELECT * FROM' of the table. When an updated batch of data is put into a new table the view is then updated to point at the new table. This means an in-place rename of the table does not need to take place that might mean downtime. This is in a version of Postgres before 9.3 where materialized views came in, just to clarify. These tables generally have about 100 million rows in them.

This is understandably leading to some confusing results when people are querying these views with very inconsistent query times. Sometimes queries are taking seconds, other times 20 or 30 milliseconds.

Additional: This is geospatial data, so they're doing geospatial queries on a view.

I know what many of the pitfalls here are - views are created on-the-fly like a sub-query, you're very much at the whim of the query planner as to what predicates get brought down and how long results are cached as results aren't physically stored as tables - but can anyone see anything else and suggest a better way of doing this? I can imagine this would be a reasonably common scenario so it might help others.

Thanks,

Comment: Who is complaining? Business people? Managers? Good luck to explain to them anything... They usually know "so much" about databases... And what they love mostly are discussions about the name of the new column in the database.... They can spend hours on this "important topic"....

Comment: No, these people are reasonably technical (or appear to be) and mostly have an Oracle background.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this reminds me a use case for synonym. However, there are no synonyms in Postgres and they recommend using Views and or separation by schema

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/kon2r2$mo6$1@ger.gmane.org